# modifying a gem changes won't take effect

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I am trying to modify the albino gem slightly but any change I make to it does not take effect including ones that should break the gem like dropping everything in the python script https://github.com/austinbv/albino/blob/master/vendor/multipygmentize to one line.

The gem was installed with bundler, and I am using rvm. The gem is stored in `~/.rvm/gems/ruby_version@project` I tried editing what I wanted directly, and I tried using
`EDITOR=vim bundle open albino` and and editing what I wanted.  Both of these did not work.

I cannot make any changes to the gem or even break it.

How do you modify a gem so that the changes will take effect.

Comment: How are you executing the gem code? From a rails app? From stand-along code? Have you tried running it's test suite, assuming it has one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer I could find is to uninstall and reinstall the gem I modified it.  Not an idea solution but worked for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

rails reload only application's classes, not gems dependencies. if you use passenger in development, use "touch tmp/always_restart.txt", else restart application every time you do any changes in gem